# Issue in showing buttons

Tags: jquery, css

Here is a div which has a span and a button. The span contains a checkbox and its text.

```
<div style="margin-top:10px;" id="dvCopysave">
    <span id="spancopy">
        <input type="checkbox" id="DynamicCopy" class="checkall" style="font-size: medium;border-width:medium;margin-left:375px" onclick="DynamicCopy_Onclick()" />
        <b> Copy data to other panels </b> &nbsp; &nbsp;
    </span>
    <button id="DynamicAdd" type="button" onclick="DynamicSave_Onclick()">
        Save
    </button>
</div>
```

In doucment.ready, there is a condition check and manage the visibility:

```
if (@Model.Target == 2)//Inspection details ->questions
{
    var panels='@Model.srPanelList';
    var lst=panels.split('|');

    $("#id").css("display", "none");

    if(lst.length-1>1)
    {
        document.getElementById("spancopy").style.visibility='visible';              
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("spancopy").style.visibility='hidden';               
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine, but when the spancopy is not visible, the position of save button is not changing, it is still the same.  So look and feel has small issue.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `visibility` doesn't affect the box area occupied by the element. If you want to remove the area occupied as well, set `display` property of that element to `none`.

Answer (score 4):

that's because of `...style.visibility='hidden'`. `visibility:hidden` means the element is not seen on the page, but space is allocated hence takes the space. So instead of `visibility`, you need to use `display`, like:

```
...
if(lst.length-1>1)
{
    document.getElementById("spancopy").style.display='block';              
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("spancopy").style.display='none';               
}
...
```

`display:none` makes the element disappear with no space allocated to it.

Comment: this is the correct answer. You got ahead of me by a minute. good job mate